# MonoTouch View Design

Tags: interface, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Being new to MonoTouch this is a best practice type of question.

If in the current view I am designing in IB I am trying to showcase existing portfolio work, e.g. as on: http://www.attitudedesign.co.uk/portfolio/

And in the app I want to show 5 portfolio items in the following linear list format:
   | Heading |
    Text Copy |
    Image |

What is the best way to go around creating this type of view?

Surely, it cant be dynamically creating Labels, Text, Images to add to the current view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UITableViewController, [here](http://www.shrinkrays.net/articles/monotouch-controllers-by-example/uitableviewcontroller-by-example.aspx) is a good example.  It explains all the basics of using UITableViews and the default cell styles, etc.

But in the end, you'll need to make a custom UITableViewCell to get what you want.  An example of that is [here](http://simon.nureality.ca/?p=91).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should check Miguel's great extension [MonoTouch.Dialog on GitHub](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) or [this article in his Blog](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Feb-23.html).
There are some cell templates included which may fit your needs. You may even use the ImageLoader for optimized usage of web-images.

I had no fun using UITableViews directly with custom DataSources at all.

Comment: This was very helpful to me too. I wish I could give dual credit.